# 500 - Internal server error with web.config in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, web-config, internal-server-error

I am working on a windows shared server and the following is my web config file when i add this i am getting the 500 Internal server Error what is the reason?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState mode="StateServer" cookieless="false" timeout="60"/>
    <machineKey decryptionKey="AC48DC02356AA0F4F1A2F7BCC6DA978E4EA8EB9ED51EEE60,IsolateApps"                validationKey="3C439A37FCCD52040B1FD56A8447DA2B8AB2B568EBC732017039593D86DC6BECF09B4F42972C91151CA8C856C702897C2B45D669BA15B0441BB13BC673010E99,IsolateApps" />
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.0" />
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="cc1" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Connection" connectionString="Data Source=199.79.xx.xx;Initial Catalog=catalog;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=xxxxx;Connect Timeout=100" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

This was working fine till few days before but when i add another website to same server with almost same config its getting error.

Comment: Look into the error stack, asp.net error page must display the error clearly.

Comment: I've edited your question to remove your password from the connection string. But it was visible for half an hour. So unless it is a local password I suggest you change it.

Comment: It was just a local password

Comment: Show IIS message details when the error being caught/thrown. Also include stack trace to point out the problem.